# supabase edge functions response Function not found

Tags: supabase

I try to develop supabase edge functions

step1: run `supabase start`

```
Seeding data supabase/seed.sql...
Started supabase local development setup.

         API URL: http://127.0.0.1:54321
     GraphQL URL: http://127.0.0.1:54321/graphql/v1
          DB URL: postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:54322/postgres
      Studio URL: http://127.0.0.1:54323
    Inbucket URL: http://127.0.0.1:54324
      JWT secret: super-secret-jwt-token-with-at-least-32-characters-long
        anon key: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZS1kZW1vIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJleHAiOjE5ODM4MTI5OTZ9.CRXP1A7WOeoJeXxjNni43kdQwgnWNReilDMblYTn_I0
service_role key: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZS1kZW1vIiwicm9sZSI6InNlcnZpY2Vfcm9sZSIsImV4cCI6MTk4MzgxMjk5Nn0.EGIM96RAZx35lJzdJsyH-qQwv8Hdp7fsn3W0YpN81IU
```

step2: run `supabase functions serve hello`

```
Setting up Edge Functions runtime...
Serving functions on http://127.0.0.1:54321/functions/v1/<function-name>
```

when i test the server

step3:
`curl -i --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:54321/functions/v1/hello' \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZS1kZW1vIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJleHAiOjE5ODM4MTI5OTZ9.CRXP1A7WOeoJeXxjNni43kdQwgnWNReilDMblYTn_I0' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data '{"name":"Functions"}'`

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 18
Connection: keep-alive
vary: Accept-Encoding
date: Mon, 06 Nov 2023 15:37:23 GMT
X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 1
X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 0
Via: kong/2.8.1

Function not found%
```

I get error message，why？？ Thanks!

Comment: The default local URL for Supabase should be `http://localhost:54321`, but do you have any additional configuration that you have setup to change the URL to `http://127.0.0.1:54321`? Are you using mac, linux, or windows?

Comment: Have done,i set the the step error

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and discovered it was because I was calling the

```
supabase start 
supabase functions serve
```

commands from inside the supabase directory when I actually should have been running them from the directory above that so that the commands could see the supabase directory in the working directory.

If anyone else runs into this I suggest starting from scratch and following the [step by step](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions/quickstart#create-an-edge-function) instructions to create the hello-world function here again, confirm that those work, then look for what may be different with what you were doing.